# Scope in enumerated type

Tags: javascript, constructor, scope, this

I was looking at an example taken from the book "Javascript: the definitive guide" published by O'Reilly. Here an enumeration function is reported:

```
function enumeration(namesToValues) {
     // This is the dummy constructor function that will be the return value.
     var enumeration = function() { throw "Can't Instantiate Enumerations"; };

     // Enumerated values inherit from this object.
    var proto = enumeration.prototype = {
    constructor: enumeration, // Identify type
    toString: function() { return this.name; }, // Return name
    valueOf: function() { return this.value; }, // Return value
    toJSON: function() { return this.name; } // For serialization
    };

    enumeration.values = []; // An array of the enumerated value objects

    // Now create the instances of this new type.
    for(name in namesToValues) { // For each value
    var e = inherit(proto); // Create an object to represent it
    e.name = name; // Give it a name
    e.value = namesToValues[name]; // And a value
    enumeration[name] = e; // Make it a property of constructor
    enumeration.values.push(e); // And store in the values array
    }

    // A class method for iterating the instances of the class
    enumeration.foreach = function(f,c) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.values.length; i++) f.call(c,this.values[i]);
    };

    // Return the constructor that identifies the new type
    return enumeration;
}
```

I  am confused to say the least.

Here we report an `enumeration` function at the first line and inside of it there is a constructor with exactly the same name. I assume we are not referring to the same function (a call from the global environment would call the first line `enumeration` and not the constructor, correct?).

we assign to `proto` the `enumeration.prototype`. What are we referring to now? Are we adding the `enumeration.prototype` property to `enumeration` function on the first line or to the constructor on the third line?

Then we are assigning the `enumeration` constructor to the `constructor` property. Why does it refer to the constructor on the third line and not to the first line `enumeration`? Is it because of the constructor being in the internal scope?

Then we declare `enumeration.values`. Again are we adding a property to the function on the first line?

Finally, what does the function return? Itself? An object?

I am unexperienced with javascript so I may be missing obvious details.

Comment: It is a very bad book if it raised as many issue rather that provide answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is one main point that confuses you: The two uses of `enumeration`.

To make it easier to explain, I will call the `enumeration` on the first line `outerEnumeration` and the one on the third line `innerEnumeration`.

### I assume we are not referring to the same function

**Yes, they are indeed two different functions**

In a global scope, yes, `enumeration` would refer to the function declared on the first line (aka. `outerEnumeration`). If there were no `var enumeration` declaration, `enumeration` inside `outerEnumeration` would refer to itself as well.

But since the `var enumeration` is declared inside the function scope, it takes precedence. Thus there is an `innerEnumeration` which is referred to by the variable `enumeration`:

```
var enumeration = function() { throw "Can't Instantiate Enumerations"; };
```

You might want to [take a closer look at JavaScript scope](http://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/) to better understand the issue at hand.

### we assign to proto the enumeration.prototype. What are we referring to now?

**To the `innerEnumeration`**

The `var enumeration` declaration is valid throughout the function body of the `outerEnumeration`, as it isn't overridden anywhere.

### Then we are assigning the enumeration constructor to the constructor property. Why does it refer to the constructor on the third line and not to the first line enumeration?

**Same reason as above**

### Then we declare enumeration.values. Again are we adding a property to the function on the first line?

**Again, the `innerEnumeration` function object**

### Finally, what does the function return? Itself? An object?

**The `innerEnumeration`**

It returns the `innerEnumeration` function with all its properties (`.prototype`, `.values`, etc.). Then, instances of `innerEnumeration` can be created. For example via:

```
new enumeration(namesToValues);
```

or

```
Object.create(enumeration.prototype).constructor(namesToValues);
```

(here `enumeration` refers to `outerEnumeration`).

I hope this helps you to understand the inner workings of this function a little bit better. Do you have any more questions?